# Проекты C# в VS 2022 очень долго запускаются

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Когда стартую проекты C# через F5, то он начинает нереально долго подгружать отладочные символы и соответственно очень долго загружается. Обычная консолька на пару строк кода может загружаться по 3 минуты. Дело в ПК? Нет. На работе у меня ПК хуже, чем дома, но проекты там стартуют быстрее. К слову, если из консоли попробовать `dotnet run`, то проект запускается шустро. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: профайлером пройдитесь и посмотрите, гадать можно вечно ;)

Comment: ¿У вас там случаем не отладочные символы подгружаются?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков зачем? Консоль на 4 строки компилируется 3 минуты, там просто пару математических ОЧЕНЬ ПРОСТЫХ выражений типа 2+2.. там нечему грузиться долго

Comment: @user7860670 я не знаю, как это проверить?

Comment: _Дело в ПК?_ - Да. 1) убедитесь, что у вас SSD, а не HDD. 2) убедитесь что оперативы достаточно, и винда не качает свап. _В чем может быть проблема?_ - в том что старт из консоли не тащит за собой отладчик и прочие профайлеры. _ПК хуже_ - чем именно? Процессором? Кто сказал, что узкое место в вашем случае в процессоре?

Comment: В окошке вывода Visual Studio будет писаться, что подгружаются символы.

Comment: @aepot нет, дело не в пк. Да, ссд. Да, оперативы достаточно, пк хуже на работе всем, у меня больше ОЗУ, ссд + хард намного больше чем на работе (на работе вообще ссд нет), процессор мощнее.

Comment: @user7860670 да, я об этом и написал в вопросе, я думал это подгружаются зависимости, но там написано "символы" как вы и написали

Comment: Что показывает диспетчер задач или монитор системных ресурсов при старте приложения? На что нагрузка?

Comment: @aepot на ОЗУ, но её хватает

Comment: Обычно даже при медленном интернете символы подгружаются медленно только в первый раз. Проверьте настройки используемых серверов символов или вообще запретите их подгрузку.

Comment: У вас больше ОЗУ - а свободного ОЗУ у вас много? Может у вас ОЗУ чем-нибудь забито, мало ли. Хотя вообще странно, с SSD вообще летать должно, впрочем, они тоже разные бывают.

Comment: @user7860670 ну у меня слабенький интернет, 100 мб. А как их отключить? Смогу ли я после этого дебажить свой код?

Comment: @CrazyElf свободного озу еще 45% (если грохнуть все вкладки гугла то еще больше будет)

Comment: Символы с сервера MS грузятся для системных компонентов, свой код можно без них отлаживать. Отключаются в настойках VS в разделе Symbols.

Comment: _на ОЗУ, но её хватает_ - как вы это поняли? Вообще нагрузка может идти либо на процессор, либо на диск. Если оператива загружена на более, чем 90% - проблема может быть даже в этом. Проведите обслуживание, почистите %TEMP%, поставьте все обновления, запустите cleanmgr, отлючите восстановление системы в настройках системного раздела, удалите точки восстановления системы, удалите ненужное ПО. Проверьте работу антивируса, это кстати тоже хороший источник тормозов.

Comment: Убедитесь, что в настройках отладки включен режим Just My Code. В противном случае отладчик будет отлаживать дотнет, а не только ваше приложение.

Comment: @aepot помогло включить Just My Code и теперь быстро загружается, только вот эта галочка не позволяет дебажить МОЙ код в том числе )

Comment: Перезапустите студию, у меня JMC отладка работает без проблем. Убедитесь что вы запускаете Debug сборку, а не Release.

Answer (score 2):

Что помогло пофиксить проблему:

`Tools` -> `Options` -> `Debugging` -> `General` -> `Enable Just My Code`

Однако, после включения может получится так, что нельзя будет дебажить и свой код тоже.

Что нужно сделать чтобы решить эту проблему:

1. Убедитесь, что находитесь в Debug-моде
2. `Debugging` -> `Symbols` -> `Load only specified modules`  и нажать на ссылку снизу `specify included modules`(см. скриншот), в появившемся окне необходимо выбрать 2 чекбокса: `Always load symbols located next to modules` и `Automatically load additionaly symbols when needed`

[image: см. скриншот]